ValueError: The length of the pixel data in the dataset (475876 bytes) doesn't match the expected length (524288 bytes)
I am trying to read the DIACOM images and convert them into the jpg why this error has been occured while reading the images with extention .dcm
What should be done to solve this problem?
Does the size of images matter or the data type?

firstly, yes the size matter, you need your images to all be the same size, and stored the same way, that's what preprocessing is for.
However i'm not sure i understand what you are trying to do, if you want to use deep-learning to turn dicom into jpg, please be aware that there exist a way to do this algorithmically, you can find more about that here https://medium.com/@vivek8981/dicom-to-jpg-and-extract-all-patients-information-using-python-5e6dd1f1a07d and also here read and open dicom images using python, it's less complete but that's where i found the first link
If that's not what you are trying to do, or you still want to do it, here's how i'd go about the preprocessing:
first set a size for the biggest image you are willing to, all of the image you use will be set to this size, either by filling with black pixels or cutting
then extract the pixels from each of your image:
import pydicom as dicom

def extract(path):
    ds = dicom.dcmread(image_path)
    return ds.pixel_array

then fill or cut each image, i'm not including that step because it's a lot of code but not very complex:

find the size diff
fill the first rows
fill the start and end of middle row
fill the last rows

and the same thing for cutting
once you're done with that you put all the picture in a list and start training
to export image to jpg, just do:
import cv2
cv2.imwrite(path + '.jpg', pixel_array)```

